# Axiomatic formal language theory

Tags: formal-languages, philosophy, semigroups

I am struggling with this problem of philosophy of mathematics, that is to apply the axiomatic method to give foundations to the theory of formal languages, without mention explicitly the concepts of "set", "order", "number", "finitude" etc. The axioms may imply implicitly these features (and they absolutely will), but not to use them. The task is to create the theory of formal languages like no previous mathematics (formal or conceptual) exists. My idea is introducing axioms that constructs an universe of things called "strings" that behaves like a free semigroup. I got stuck on the problem of introducing an axiom that imply the freeness of the "semigroup" of strings.

I begun with the primitive notions of "string" (word) and "concatenation" (juxtaposition) and the semigroup axioms:

> **(A1)** For each pair of strings $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there is a unique string (denoted by "$\alpha \beta$") called "concatenation of $\alpha$ followed by $\beta$".
>
> **(A2)** For any strings $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, if $\delta$ is $\alpha \beta$ and $\varepsilon$ is $\beta \gamma$, then $\delta \gamma$ is $\alpha \varepsilon$. This string is denoted by "$\alpha \beta \gamma$".

We say that a string $\alpha$ is a concatenation (is decomposable) if and only if there exists strings $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha$ is $\beta \gamma$. In this case we call $\beta$ a left-divisor of $\alpha$ and we call $\gamma$ a right-divisor of $\alpha$. We call both $\beta$ and $\gamma$ divisors of $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is not decomposable we call it indecomposable or we say that $\alpha$ is a symbol, ie, $\alpha$ has no divisors.

Then I postulate an axiom

> **(A3)** There exists symbols.

Now I need to postulate axioms that imply (implicitly) that this semigroup of strings is freely generated by the "set" of symbols. That is, every string is a uniquelly finite concatenation of symbols. The usual intuitive way to say this is: for every string $\alpha$, there exists a unique finite number of symbols, say $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, ..., $\sigma_n$, such that $\alpha$ is the concatenation $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 ... \sigma_n \, $. But I am not permitted to mention numbers, order or finitude (or to write the dots "...").

---

**First attempt.**

I postulate the cancellation laws.

> **(A4)** For any strings $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, if $\alpha \beta$ is $\alpha \gamma$, then $\beta$ is $\gamma$.
>
> **(A5)** For any strings $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, if $\beta \alpha$ is $\gamma \alpha$, then $\beta$ is $\gamma$.

And some axioms.

> **(A6)** If $\alpha$ is a string that is not a symbol, then there exists a symbol $x$ and a string $\beta$ such that $\alpha$ is $x \beta$.
>
> **(A7)** If $\alpha$ is a string that is not a symbol, then there exists a symbol $y$ and a string $\beta$ such that $\alpha$ is $\beta y$.
>
> **(A8)** For any symbols $x$ and $y$ and any strings $\alpha$ and $\beta$, if $x \alpha$ is $y \beta$, then $x$ is $y$.
>
> **(A9)** For any symbols $x$ and $y$ and any strings $\alpha$ and $\beta$, if $\alpha x$ is $\beta y$, then $x$ is $y$.

From (A6) and (A7), informally, I can recursivelly express a string in a sequence of symbols and a medium string in a way like this $$\alpha = x_1 \alpha_1 y_1 = x_1 x_2 \alpha_2 y_2 y_1 = x_1 x_2 x_3 \alpha_3 y_3 y_2 y_1 = \ ...$$ but I can't see a way to make it stop at a finite number of steps, ie, say that for some natural number $n$ the string $\alpha_n$ is a symbol. This will do the work of the "set" of strings to be generated by the "set" of symbols.

From (A4), (A5), (A8) and (A9) I can do the cancellations recursivelly. That is, if $\alpha$ is $\beta$ and, by above, $$\alpha = x_1 \alpha_1 y_1 = x_1 x_2 \alpha_2 y_2 y_1 = x_1 x_2 x_3 \alpha_3 y_3 y_2 y_1 = \ ...$$ and $$\beta = a_1 \beta_1 b_1 = a_1 a_2 \beta_2 b_2 b_1 = a_1 a_2 a_3 \beta_3 b_3 b_2 b_1 = \ ... \ , $$ then $x_j$ is $a_j$, $y_j$ is $b_j$ and $\alpha_j$ is $\beta_j$, for all $j$. Again halting this process is a thing that I could not manage to do.

---

**Second attempt.**

I found the book "The algebraic theory of semigroups" vol. 2, by Clifford and Preston. At page 118, they mention a theorem by Levi and Dubreil-Jacotin transcripted bellow (with a remark)

> **(L&D-J)** The semigroup $S$ is a free semigroup if and only if it satisfies each of the following conditions:
>
> **(1)** the left and right cancellation laws hold in $S$;
>
> **(2)** $S$ contains no two-sided identity element;
>
> **(3)** if $ \ ax=by \ $ for $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$ in $S$, then $ \ a=b \ $ or $ \ a=bu \ $ or $ \ b=av \ $ for $u$, $v$ in $S$;
>
> **(4)** each element of $S$ has only a finite number of left divisors.
>
> **Remark.** Conditions (3) and (4) of the preceding theorem can be replaced by their left-right duals, when the conclusion of the theorem will continue to hold.

The condition (1) of the theorem above is (A4) and (A5) togheter. The condition (2) can be easilly made an axiom

> **(A10)** There is no string $\lambda$ with the property that, for any string $\alpha$, $\lambda \alpha$ is $\alpha$ and, for any string $\beta$, $\beta \lambda$ is $\beta$.

Condition (3) of (L&D-J) can be made an axiom rewriting it

> **(A11)** For any strings $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$, if $\alpha \gamma$ is $\beta \delta$, then $\alpha$ is $\beta$ or there exist some string $\varepsilon$ such that $\alpha$ is $\beta \varepsilon$ ($\beta$ is a left-divisor of $\alpha$) or there exist some string $\omega$ such that $\beta$ is $\alpha \omega$ ($\alpha$ is a left-divisor of $\beta$).

But condition (4) of the theorem is the problem here. I could not rewrite it without explicit mention the concept of finitude, order or number.

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe useful Tarski and [Andrzej Grzegorczyk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrzej_Grzegorczyk)'s *theory of concatenation*; see: Andrzej Grzegorczyk, [Undecidability without Arithmetization](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20016684), Studia Logica (2005).

Comment: For formal languages and groups, see: Ian Chiswell, [A Course in Formal Languages Automata and Groups](https://books.google.it/books?id=hjxdQLOrw3QC&pg=PA93), Springer (2009), **Ch.5 Connections with Group Theory**, page 93-on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am reading the 2005 Grzegorczyk's paper. At page 169 he says that the general cancellations schemas are not provable in TC. But, if I remember, these schemas are provable in a free semigroup. This implies that the semigroup of strings of TC is not free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we rephrase the question, you are asking for a set of formulae of first-order logic in the signature of semigroups that define uniquely the notion of a free semigroup.

So the question is to find a family

$F = \varphi_1, \varphi_2, \dots$

of first-order sentence in the signature of semigroups (i.e., a binary operator '.'), such that there is exactly one model of $F$ (a **model** is of $F$ is a structure that satisfies all the sentences of $F$ simultaneously), and this structure corresponds to standard words: let us call $W$ be the **structure of standard words**:

- the elements are the nonempty words,
- the unique binary operation `.' is interpreted as concatenation.

This is impossible: whatever is the choice of $F$ that you make, if $W$ is a model of $F$, then there exists another model for $F$ that is not isomorphism to $W$. This is a consequence of the compactness theorem in model theory.

[**Compactness:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem)
For all sets of formulae $E$, if every finite subset of $E$ has a model, then $E$ has a model.

Here is how to use is. We throw a new constant $\alpha$. Note first that that you can provide for all $n$ a formula $\psi_n$ that means `the word $\alpha$ has length at least $n$'. Let $E=\{\psi_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and consider now the set of formulae:

$F\cup E$.

Assume now that $F$ has as model the standard words $W$, then every finite subset of $F\cup E$ has a model. Indeed, every finite sets of formulae contain finitely many formulae from $E$, so it is sufficient to take as model $W$ together with $\alpha$ as chosen to be a sufficiently long word. By compactness, this means that there exists a model that satisfies simultaneously all the formulae in $F\cup E$. This model contains thus a word, more precisely $\alpha$, that has the property of being `longer than every number $n$'. This model cannot be the standard one $W$.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to define uniquely the notion of free semigroup. What does it mean to define uniquely? Another thing: why I need to exist exactly one model of $F$?

Comment: @Gustavo In the part "From (A6) and (A7), informally, I can recursively express...", what you are attempting to prove is that the objects that you re constructing can be identified with the ones of normal mathematics. This is why I have shown you that this is impossible: it is not possible to provide a set of first-order sentences that has the property that the model is exactly the one of the ambient (said differently, that the unique model is the standard one, hence the terminology 'uniqueness').

Comment: @Gustavo In the part __"From (A6) and (A7), informally, I can recursively express..."__, you try to identify the objects that are axiomatized with words of normal mathematics. In my answer I have shown you that this is impossible (said differently, you can't enforce that the unique model is the standard one, hence the terminology 'uniqueness').

However, if you want to work with your notion as normal words, then you should look at axiom templates similar to induction. (if $P(a)$ holds, for every letter $a$, and $P(\alpha)$ implies $P(\alpha a)$ then $P(\alpha)$ holds for every $\alpha$).

Comment: Now I think I finally understood your answer. You showed that there is no set of first order axioms that builds a theory in which the sentence "every string is a finite concatenation of symbols" is a theorem. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that this is not possible. That is:

So far mathematicians were not able to construct axioms of the natural numbers, that exclude all non-finite models that satisfy this axioms.

Maybe a little bit easier to understand: There are [nonstandard models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) of the natural numbers, that include "infinite" numbers.

You will have the same problem, that each of your axioms will essentially create a model, that includes infinite strings. There are even proofs, that show that it is not possilbe to exclude these models, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Nonstandard_models).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this is helpful to solve my problem.

Comment: @Gustavo I doens't help at all^^
All I'm saying is that you will not be able to find an axiomatic setting for finiteness of your strings, as this is not possible (according to the current knowledge). So you might just be satisfied with what you have, that is your axioms without mentioning finiteness.

Comment: Well, I am not an expert but I think we can construct $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X^n$ within ZFC for any set $X$. While this would enlarge the list of axioms much more than I would like.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but this doesn't help, because this depends on the model of $\mathbb{N}$. And you cant force this version of $\mathbb{N}$ to have only finite elements. That means this definition of finiteness is also not useful. Believe me, there is no way to define (in an axiomatic way) what finite means.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why I need a model for $\mathbb{N}$. I used to think that it is just the set $\omega$ of finite ordinals and that it exists as a consequence of the axiom of infinity. Sure there is some subtlety I am missing here.

Comment: For each set of axioms, there are different models that satisfy your axioms. These are all isomorphic (if your axioms are "good", which in your case they might be). However, not all of them will only allow finite strings, in your non-mathematical interpretation of finite. You can't axiomatize finitness, it's just not possible. Your axioms already do as good as possible, you will not be able do add axioms, that will fullfill a definition of finite.